# Is OpenSSH sending an email to no-more-sessions@openssh.com every time I connect?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

When I try to connect to my EC2 (Ubuntu 14.04.3) server with `ssh -v server`, I see this at the end of the log:

```
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <domain>.com ([192.168.1.42]:12345).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com  # <!-!-!-!-!-!- What's this?
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-55-generic x86_64)
```

This is my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
  HostName domain.com
  User myuser
  IdentityFile ~/path/to/EC2Key.pem
  Port <portnumber>
```

Which seems normal. I can see two possible reasons here:

1. OpenSSH is trying to make a connection to `openssh.com` as a user `no-more-sessions` - but that doesn't make any sense either, why?
2. OpenSSH is trying to send email to `no-more-sessions@openssh.com`. This makes even less sense, and both options seem a little creepy.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, that's not an email address. The `something@domain` syntax is used in many other places, and SSHv2 uses it for naming all "nonstandard" extensions (ciphers, subsystems, and so on).

So this particular request has `@openssh.com` because it was invented by OpenSSH, and hasn't been made part of the "main" standard documents.

Its purpose is explained in the [OpenSSH 5.1 release notes](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.1):

> - Added a no-more-sessions@openssh.com global request extension that is
>     sent from ssh(1) to sshd(8) when the client knows that it will never
>     request another session (i.e. when session multiplexing is disabled). 
>     This allows a server to disallow further session requests and
>     terminate the session in cases where the client has been hijacked.

Comment: Indeed. In this case, it’s something like `<thing>@<namespace>`. Another related method is the reverse domain style (whatever it’s called): `<namespace>.<thing>`